# oninput isn't calling the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run a `function` whenever an `input's` text changes. I'm using the `oninput` attribute to do that. I followed [W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp). When I try it on in my own code, (or `JSFiddle`,) the `function` doesn't get called.

#### JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 function myFunction() {
  alert("asdf");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because oninput calling a method myFunction that is out of scope. There is no reason for it to be inside the ready handler

```
//$(document).ready(function () {  <--get rid of this
    function myFunction() {
        alert("asdf");
    }
//});  <-- get rid of this
```

Now it will work

Comment: Thanks! But I just tried that, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Because your fiddle is also wrong. You have it set to run onload which means it is still out of scope.

Comment: BTW congratulations on reaching 100k! :) Waiting patiently for the day I get there!

Comment: So the only problem is, that it can't be in the ready handler? (In my actual project.) If so, why can't I leave it inside?

Comment: I understand what out of scope is, but can't I mix JavaScript and JQuery? Meaning, why can't the function be inside?

Comment: Apparently you do not because the function is not declared on the window context so you can not call it. When you declare it inside the ready handler it can only be called by methods inside that function. The ready event is like a room with all the windows blocked out. You can not see in from the outside. That is where the event is sitting. It can not see the function.